# Error when trying to package PyQt4 application on Windows 7

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to package a PyQt4 application on Windows. I have tried using cx_freeze and py2exe. However, when using cx_freeze i get the following error when I try running the executable produced:

```
ImportError: No module named image
```

This occurs despite having installed PIL.

When I use py2exe, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Here is the setup file for cx_freeze:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ["sip","requests","PyQt4","PIL"] 
exe = Executable(
    script="trial.py",
    base="Win32GUI"
    )

setup(
    options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes}},
    executables = [exe],
    data_files = [
        ('phonon_backend', [
            'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\phonon_backend\phonon_ds94.dll'
            ]),
        ('imageplugins', [
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll',
        ]),
]
    )
```

and here is the setup file for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(windows=['trial.py'],
      options={
      'py2exe': {
          "dll_excludes": [
              "MSVCP90.dll",
              "MSWSOCK.dll",
              "mswsock.dll",
              "powrprof.dll",
              ],

          'includes': [
              'sip',
              'PyQt4',
              ],
      }
  },
data_files = [
        ('phonon_backend', [
            'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\phonon_backend\phonon_ds94.dll'
            ]),
        ('imageplugins', [
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll',
        ]),
],

)
```

and here are my imports in the script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, uic
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

How can I get rid of the errors? Thanks.

Comment: What about adding `Image` to the includes in your setup.py file?

Answer (score 1):

Though not quite the answer you're looking for, in all honesty, I would recommend that you use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) if possible. I have found it to work far better than both py2exe and cx_Freeze, it is actively maintained, and it includes automatic support for PyQt4.

Comment: Seconding this, PyInstaller was my first idea when I read the question. I use it to package computing package written in c++/python using PyQt4 (and matplotlib and numpy and so on, for which there are specific hooks built-in) for frontend (http://woodem.eu), works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(windows=['trial.py'],
      options={
      'py2exe': {
          "dll_excludes": [
              "MSVCP90.dll",
              "MSWSOCK.dll",
              "mswsock.dll",
              "powrprof.dll",
              ],

          'includes': [
              'sip',
              'PyQt4.QtCore',
              'PyQt4.QtGui',
              ],
      }
  },
data_files = [
        ('phonon_backend', [
            'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\phonon_backend\phonon_ds94.dll'
            ]),
        ('imageplugins', [
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qgif4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll',
        'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll',
        ]),
],

)
```